# Access html input tag and pass to template url_for

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I want to pass the value of a html input tag (in this case taskname_in) to the url_for as a parameter.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="taskname_l">Task Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskname_in" name="taskname_in" required style="width: 500px;">
</div>

<div>
 <li><a href="{{ url_for('modal_add_depend',task_name=taskname_in???) }}" id="depend_pop1">Click to add</a></li>                             
</div>
```

Comment: You are confusing client side and server side execution here. Jinja2 executes on the server, generating HTML (and other formats) that then are loaded into the client (browser). The form is interpreted by the browser, and values entered into an input field are *not visible to the template code*.

Comment: What does the route definition for `modal_add_depend` look like? Does it have a `task_name` path variable, or is `task_name` a query parameter (`...?task_name=<value>`)?

Comment: Last but not least, with a name like `modal_add_depend`, are you expecting the URL to provide a modal dialog inside the browser window? Then you'll have to use AJAX to load the modal dialog contents anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible the way you want it to be.

The flask/jinja2 templates are rendered on the server before the page gets to the user, but the input value is accessible only when the user inputs it. You need to use some AJAX or Javascript logic.